# Why does the segment tree algorithm not work properly?

Tags: javascript

This is a segment tree algorithm problem:

The first time I initialize a method in a constructor and use it, I don't know why it went wrong?

```
Error : 
    function build_tree(arr, tree, node, start, end){
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    update_tree(this.nums, this.tree, 0, 0, this.size - 1, i, val);
```

**update**:
This function is not found on the prototype

```
update_tree(this.nums, this.tree, 0, 0, this.size - 1, i, val);
    ^
ReferenceError: update_tree is not defined
```

**update:**
`sumRange` return undefinded

The following code：

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 */
var NumArray = function (nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) return;
    this.nums = nums;
    this.size = this.nums.length;
    this.tree = [];

    build_tree(this.nums, this.tree, 0, 0, this.size - 1);

    function build_tree(arr, tree, node, start, end){
        if (start == end) {
            tree[node] == arr[start];
        } else {
            let mid = parseInt((start + end) / 2);
            let left_node = 2 * node + 1;
            let right_node = 2 * node + 2;
            build_tree(arr, tree, left_node, start, mid);
            build_tree(arr, tree, right_node, mid+1, end);
            tree[node] == tree[left_node] + tree[right_node];
        }
    }
};

/** 
 * @param {number} i 
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {void}
 */
NumArray.prototype.update = function (i, val) {

    update_tree(this.nums, this.tree, 0, 0, this.size - 1, i, val);

   function update_tree(arr, tree, node, start, end, idx, val){
        if (start == end) {
            arr[idx] = val;
            tree[node] = val;
        } else {
            let mid = parseInt((start + end) / 2);
            let left_node = 2 * node + 1;
            let right_node = 2 * node + 2;
            if (idx >= start && idx <= mid) {
                update_tree(arr, tree, left_node, start, mid, idx, val)
            } else {
                update_tree(arr, tree, right_node, mid + 1, end, idx, val)
            }
            tree[node] = tree[left_node] + tree[right_node];
        }
    }
};

/** 
 * @param {number} i 
 * @param {number} j
 * @return {number}
 */
NumArray.prototype.sumRange = function (i, j) {

    return query_tree(this.nums, this.tree, 0, 0, this.size - 1, i, j);

    function query_tree(arr, tree, node, start, end, L, R) {
        if (R < start || L > end) {
            return 0;
        } else if (start == end) {
            return arr[start];
        } else if (L <= start && end <= R) {
            return tree[node];
        } else {
            let mid = parseInt((start + end) / 2);
            let left_node = 2 * node + 1;
            let right_node = 2 * node + 2;
            let sum_left = query_tree(arr, tree, left_node, start, mid, L, R);
            let sum_right = query_tree(arr, tree, right_node, mid + 1, end, L, R);
            return sum_left + sum_right;
        }
    }
};

var obj = new NumArray([1, 3, 5]);

console.log(obj.sumRange(0, 2));
console.log(obj.update(1, 2))
console.log(obj.sumRange(0, 2));
```

Error : 
    function build_tree(arr, tree, node, start, end){
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

**update**:
This function is not found on the prototype

```
update_tree(this.nums, this.tree, 0, 0, this.size - 1, i, val);
    ^
ReferenceError: update_tree is not defined
```

**update:**
`sumRange` return undefinded

I tried to use `IIFE` , But you can't use recursion

Why?

Can you help me?

Comment: in `build_tree` , `if(start == end)` , `start` is always `0`, end will never reach `0` , because of `let mid = (start + end) / 2;` and you pass `mid` to `build_tree`

Comment: You could try `let mid = parseInt((start + end)/2);`

Comment: @Taki  I have added parseInt, I wonder why the ReferenceError: query_tree is not defined

Comment: @Amadeus I added parseInt, I wonder why the ReferenceError: query_tree is not defined

Comment: `update_tree : (...` or `update_tree = (...`. ?

Comment: @Amadeus `query_tree` and `update-tree`  Can't find

Comment: Exactly what Im showing you. You should use `=` and define it before usage

Comment: @Amadeus  I see, now there is a new problem, query_tree returns the value undefined

Comment: @Amadeus No. Don't use `parseInt` on things that already are no strings! You meant `Math.floor` probably.

Comment: Your function doesn't work on empty trees, where `start` is `0` and `end` is `-1`. I guess you'll have to adjust your base case for testing `start >= end`, instead of doing `==`.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you very much. Can you help me solve this problem? It returns undefi again